# How to pytest a POST request that calls a function containing a sql call?

Tags: python, sql, mocking, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a POST request that calls a function, passing in an ID as an argument which the child function uses in their sql query. How do I test the post request function? I get a no such table error after getting to `pd.read_sql(query, engine)` but when I SQL using MySQLworkbench, the table does exist. The function also works when ran normally without pytest.

The function I want to test:

```
getMovieBudget(movieId):
    engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
    query = """
            SELECT *
            FROM movies
            WHERE id = '{}';
            """.format(movieId)
    data = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
    return data.iloc[0]['building_id']

@function.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def test_post():
    // .. some code here
    movieId = request.form['movieId']
    movieBudget = getMovieBudget(movieId)
```

My test file:

```
def test_post(client, capsys):
    url = f'/{helpers.get_domain()}/{helpers.get_version()}/movies/'

    data = {
        'movieId': 144,
    }

    response = client.post(url, data=data)

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Running `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` returns `sqlite:////tmp/test.db`

It's because my config test file has the following:

```
os.environ['TEST_ENV'] = 'TRUE'

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_patch(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(SQLAlchemy, "create_all", mock.Mock(return_value=True))

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    from movie_handler import app

    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
    return app.test_client()
```

Comment: Before calling your getMovieBudget function, can you add assertion to check for app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], then run your test code again and edit the question with the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `pandas.read_sql` needs to be mocked like

```
@mock.patch('pandas.read_sql')
def test_post(query_mock, client, capsys):
   \\ ... some code
    d = {'movieId': [114102]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    query_mock.return_value = df
```